# Using HTML5 range sliders with Javascript Event Listener

Tags: javascript, php, html, range, addeventlistener

I am trying to build an HTML5 slider loan calculator using Javascript to display and calculate values on the fly.

The biggest issue is that I am a total rookie when it comes to Javascript.

So I have some code that I am using to display 3 sliders to get the down payment, interest rate, and term for the loan. I have successfully gotten the sliders to behave exactly as I would like, but I am having a lot of trouble calculating the total. I did have it setup to calculate the total by simply passing all of the values to the last block of javascript, but it would not update dynamically. Right now I am just trying to prove that I can get the value of one range slider to update dynamically next to its own slider and below where I plan to display the calculations. I have tried many different things, but I just can't make it work.

Here is the code that I have currently.

```
<div class="clearfix" id="finance-calculator"><!-- Begin Finance Calculator -->
<div>Estimate Your Payments</div>
<div id="finance-sale-price">$<?php echo number_format(($sale_price) , 2 , '.' , ',' )?></div>
<div class="sale-price-label">Sale Price</div>

<div id="down-block">
<?php 
$down_max = ceil($sale_price * 0.9);
$down_init = ceil ($sale_price * 0.2);
echo '<div class="output-label">$<output for="down_slider" id="down">' . $down_init . '</output><p class="value-label">Down Payment</p></div>';
echo '<input type="range" min="0" max="' . $down_max . '" value="' . $down_init . '" id="down-slider" step="1" oninput="outputDown(value)"/>';
?>
    <div class="minimum">0%</div>
    <div class="maximum">90%</div>
    <script>
        function outputDown(downVal) {
            document.querySelector('#down').value = downVal;
        }
    </script>
</div>

<div id="rate-block">
    <div class="output-label"><output for="rate_slider" id="rate">5.9</output>% APR<p class="value-label">Interest Rate</p></div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="12" value="5.9" id="rate-slider" step="0.1" oninput="outputRate(value)"/>
    <div class="minimum">0%</div>
    <div class="maximum">12%</div>
    <script>
        function outputRate(rateVal) {
            document.querySelector('#rate').value = rateVal;
        }
    </script>
</div>

<div id="term-block">
    <div class="output-label"><output for="term-slider" id="term">60</output> Months<p class="value-label">Loan Term</p></div>
    <input type="range" min="12" max="84" value="60" id="term-slider" step="12" oninput="outputTerm(value)"/>
    <div class="minimum">12 months</div>
    <div class="maximum">84 months</div>
    <script>
        function outputTerm(termVal) {
            document.querySelector('#term').value = termVal;
        }
    </script>
</div>

<div id="total-block">
    Testing
    <script>
        var jdown = document.getElementById("down"); // Variable to store dynamic down payment value
        jdown.addEventListener('change', function(){document.write (jdown)}, false);    // Event listener to update jdown variable when slider above is used. document.write to test. 
    </script>
    Testing
</div>
```

A live example of this can be seen at: http://forestlakechev.staging.wpengine.com/inventory/2015/Chevrolet/Cruze/MN/Forest%20Lake/1G1PA5SH0F7130316/?

Next to the images of the vehicle is some tabbed content. Click on the finance tab and you will see the calculator as it currently is.

I am trying to keep this as simple as possible, but I am just stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Jared

Comment: You don't need to `echo` all stuff using PHP. Simply close the PHP tag using `?>` and write your HTML/Javascript/whatever. If you need to use PHP again, simply open a PHP code block using `<?php` again.

Comment: @AlejandroIván Done! I have removed all of the unnecessary php echo statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to solve this myself with some extreme trial and error.

I am sure that there are many better ways to do this, but I am just happy to have it working. I would be very happy to get any input regarding how this can be improved. Here is the updated code:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="finance-calculator" onload="outputLoad()"><!-- Begin Finance Calculator -->

<?php
    $init_payment = ((($sale_price * 0.8)*(1 + (0.059*5)))/60);
?>

<script>
    function outputDown(downVal,rate,term) {
        var jdown = downVal; 
        document.querySelector('#down').value = jdown;
        var testDown = document.getElementById('testDown');

        var rate = document.getElementById(rate).value;
        rate = (rate * 0.01).toFixed(3);
        var term = document.getElementById(term).value;
        var years = (term/12);
        var price = <?php echo ($sale_price) ?>;
        payment.innerHTML = "$"+(((price - jdown)*(1 + (rate*years)))/term).toFixed(2);

    }

    function outputRate(rateVal,down,term) {
        var jrate = rateVal; 
        document.querySelector('#rate').value = jrate;
        var testRate = document.getElementById('testRate');

        var down = document.getElementById(down).value;
        jrate = (jrate * 0.01).toFixed(3);
        var term = document.getElementById(term).value;
        var years = (term/12);
        var price = <?php echo ($sale_price) ?>;
        payment.innerHTML = "$"+(((price - down)*(1 + (jrate*years)))/term).toFixed(2);

    }

    function outputTerm(termVal,down,rate) {
        var jterm = termVal; 
        document.querySelector('#term').value = jterm;
        var testTerm = document.getElementById('testTerm');

        var down = document.getElementById(down).value;
        var rate = document.getElementById(rate).value;
        rate = (rate * 0.01).toFixed(3);
        var years = (jterm/12);
        var price = <?php echo ($sale_price) ?>;
        payment.innerHTML = "$"+(((price - down)*(1 + (rate*years)))/jterm).toFixed(2);

    }
</script>

<div>Estimate Your Payments</div>
<div><a href="#tab-2">Value Your Trade Here!</a></div>
<div id="price">$<?php echo number_format(($sale_price) , 2 , '.' , ',' )?></div>
<div class="sale-price-label">Sale Price</div>

<div id="down-block">
    <?php 
        $down_max = ceil($sale_price * 0.9);
        $down_init = ceil ($sale_price * 0.2);
    ?>
    <div class="output-label">$<output for="down_slider" id="down"><?php echo ($down_init) ?></output><p class="value-label">Down Payment</p></div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="<?php echo ($down_max) ?>" value="<?php echo ($down_init) ?>" id="down-slider" step="1" oninput="outputDown(value,'rate','term')"/>
    <div class="minimum">0%</div>
    <div class="maximum">90%</div>
</div>

<div id="rate-block">
    <div class="output-label"><output for="rate_slider" id="rate">5.9</output>% APR<p class="value-label">Interest Rate</p></div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="12" value="5.9" id="rate-slider" step="0.1" oninput="outputRate(value,'down','term')"/>
    <div class="minimum">0%</div>
    <div class="maximum">12%</div>
</div>

<div id="term-block">
    <div class="output-label"><output for="term-slider" id="term">60</output> Months<p class="value-label">Loan Term</p></div>
    <input type="range" min="12" max="84" value="60" id="term-slider" step="12" oninput="outputTerm(value,'down','rate')"/>
    <div class="minimum">12 months</div>
    <div class="maximum">84 months</div>
</div>

<div id="total-block">
    <p id="payment">$<?php echo number_format(($init_payment) , 2 , '.' , ',' )?></p>
    <p class="payment-label">Monthy Payment</p>
</div>
```

A working example of this can be found at: http://forestlakechev.staging.wpengine.com/inventory/2015/Chevrolet/Cruze/MN/Forest%20Lake/1G1PA5SH0F7130316/?

Jared